# Image Chooser not working for 5.0 and how to upload multiple image

Tags: android, android-webview

This code is for web view where I am fetching webpage page in that web page there is image choosing activity which upload one image not a multiple image.I wanted to upload multiple image.

So please narrate me what wrong in it and how make work image choose above android version as 5.0+

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE =1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE =2;
    private static final String TAG =MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessages;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI=null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhoto;



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessages) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result=null;

            try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessages = null;

        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=19)  {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl("http://m.multitechservice.co.in");
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws Exception{

        String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        String imageFileName= "JPEG_" + timeStamp +  "_";
        File storageDirectory=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile=File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDirectory);
        return imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(mFilePathCallback != null){
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback=filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){

                File photoFile=null;
                try{
                    photoFile=createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("Photo_Path", mCameraPhoto);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file path",ex);
                }

                if(photoFile!=null){
                    mCameraPhoto="file:" +photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

                }else{
                    takePictureIntent=null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentOnSelection=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentOnSelection.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentOnSelection.setType("image/*");


            Intent[] intentArray;

            if(takePictureIntent!=null){
                intentArray=new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            }else{
                intentArray =new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentOnSelection);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMSG,String acceptType){

            mUploadMessages=uploadMSG;

            File imageStorage=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Photo");

            if(!imageStorage.exists()){
                imageStorage.mkdirs();
            }

            File file=new File(imageStorage +File.separator +"IMG_" +String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI=Uri.fromFile(file);


            final Intent captureIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");


            Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(intent, "IMAGE CHOOSER");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] {captureIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMSG){

            openFileChooser(uploadMSG," ");

        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,String acceptType,String capture){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg,acceptType);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public class Client extends WebViewClient {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("mailto:")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
            else{
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if(progressDialog == null){
                progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading.........");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog=null;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try{
                view.stopLoading();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(view.canGoBack()){
                view.goBack();
            }

            view.loadUrl("about:blank");

            AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");

            alertDialog.setMessage("Cannot connect to Internet.Please check your internet connection");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(id == R.id.action_refresh){
            webView.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi do u got any solution. i have same problem with samsung tab 3.please post your answer if you got solution

Comment: Nope I skip it Since there are change in webview since Kitkat

Comment: i got solution to that